# How react can Identify it's a class component or functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components

I have created two component in my React App one is class component and another one is functional component. But how react can identify when it call the component it's a class component or functional component?

**It's a question ask by Interviewer**

Comment: a simple keyword search `class`? What exactly you/the interviewer trying to ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how react can identify when it calls the component it's a class component or functional component?

```
// Who is a class component and who is a functional component?
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <ComponentA />
    <ComponentB />
    {React.createElement(ComponentA)}
    {React.createElement(ComponentB)}
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

While [JSX represents objects](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects), as [stated in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) they are equivalent:

> The above two components are equivalent from React’s point of view.

But [actually](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/769b1f270e1251d9dbdce0fcbd9e92e502d059b8/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiber.js#L297-L300), React checking [`isReactComponent` flag](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/react/blob/83644185f4388834c0c482c7522a5f2f476d84a2/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js#L32) to determinate if it's a class component or function component:

```
// @ ReactComponent.js
ReactComponent.prototype.isReactComponent = {};

// @ ReactFiber.js
function shouldConstruct(Component: Function) {
  const prototype = Component.prototype;
  return !!(prototype && prototype.isReactComponent);
}
```

For more in-depth explanation check [Dan Abramov's blog post](https://overreacted.io/how-does-react-tell-a-class-from-a-function/).

Answer (score 0):

React check the component for the `isReactComponent` flag (which is present on `React.Component.prototype` [source](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/react/blob/83644185f4388834c0c482c7522a5f2f476d84a2/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js#L32)) to determine weather it's a class or a function.

You can read about it in detail here: https://overreacted.io/how-does-react-tell-a-class-from-a-function/